# PHP Number Cleaner RegEx

Tags: php, regex

I have a function I use in PHP to work with numbers.  The intent is to clean the number and, optionally, convert nulls to zero.  It began for me for use in prep for sql, but is now used in more places.  Here it is:

```
function clean_num ($num, $null_to_zero = true) {
  $num = preg_replace("/[^-0-9.0-9$]/","",$num);
  if (strlen($num) == 0)
    $num = ($null_to_zero) ? 0 : null;
  else if (strlen($num) == 1 && ($num == '-' || $num == '.'))
    $num = ($null_to_zero) ? 0 : null;
  return $num;
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas on a faster, better way of doing this?  It works, the regex is simple enough and should cover all cases I need, but...  A diff regex might do all the same without other junk.  Regex is not my strength.  Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean, "clean the number"? Is `$num` a string here?

Comment: what's the dollar for in the regex?

Comment: @Tom Haigh, looks like he's trying to clean currencies. Money launderer!

Comment: I was going to add an answer but realized that if you're not validating that it is numeric why would you clean the string to make it numeric? Basically bad data in and then cleaned is even worse data out.

Comment: would floatval or intval work for what youre trying to do? its a little unclear to me your objective.

Comment: The point is to clean numbers entered, including dollar values.  I want to strip any non-numeric and maintain decimals and negatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex `[^-0-9.0-9$]` matches any char that is

- not a hyphen
- not a digit
- not a `.`
- not a `$`

there is no need to have two `0-9` in the char class, so effectively your regex is: `[^-0-9.$]` or `[^-\d.$]`

Comment: Removing the $ from the regex gave me the exact results I wanted.  Just numbers, don't lose any precision, don't lose negatives, strip any alpha, etc.  Thanks!